# Updating Variables for Increased Bytearray Size

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently doing work which programmatically attempts to manipulate PE files. The approach so far has been to parse out all the information (headers, variables within the headers, etc) from a raw array of bytes, representing the PE file.

As a result of this I currently have approximately 70 variables each pointing to a different byte slice of the array, which represents data about the PE. The issue comes with trying to now manipulate the array, and change the file.

Lets say I wish to insert / add data at an arbitrary point along the byte array. 35 variables are before it, while 35 variables are after the insertion point. The earlier variables will be unaffected. What is the best way to update these 35 variables their position has been offset by N bytes?

Current information the variables have is a) Their value at the location they are at (typically a 4 byte little endian value), and b) Their absolute offset from the beginning of the PE file.

Cheers.

Comment: What should happen if you insert new data *inside* an existing slice?

Comment: You might wish to consider using an `collections.OrderedDict` to hold the information.

Comment: Have you considered using [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile)? pefile is a multi-platform Python module to parse and work with Portable Executable (aka PE) files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `struct` and `namedtuple` from `collections` module. Collect logical units into a `namedtuple` and use `struct` to pack/unpack those `namedtuple`s. That's one of the most 'readable' and 'maintainable' ways of going about it.

Another thing to keep in mind is to read the file in binary mode and use `read` instead of `readlines` and `tell` and `seek` to read only the things of your interest.